# instance has no __call__ method

Tags: python, class, object, call

I have written to the code below as an exercise and to do some vector algebra with an application of mine.

```
from math import acos

class Vector:

    def __init__(self,x,y,z):
        self.x = x; self.y = y; self.z = z

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.x) + "i + " + str(self.y) + "j + " + str(self.z) + "k"

    def magnitude(self):
        return self.x**2 + self.y**2 + self.z**2 

    def plus(self,Vector):
        return Vector(self.x+Vector.x,self.y+Vector.y,self.z+Vector.z)

    def minus(self,Vector):
        return Vector(self.x-Vector.x,self.y-Vector.y,self.z-Vector.z)

    def dot(self,Vector):
        return self.x*Vector.x,self.y*Vector.y,self.z*Vector.z

    def angle(self,Vector):
        return acos(self.dot(Vector)/(self.magnitude*Vector.magnitude))

    def cross(self,Vector):
        return Vector(self.x*Vector.z-self.z*Vector.y,self.z*Vector.x-self.x*Vector.z,self.x*Vector.y-self.y*Vector.x)
```

When I want create two instances (`v1` and `v2`) and use `v1.cross(v2)` I get the error below.

```
>>> v1.cross(v2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "vector_algebra.py", line 33, in cross
    return acos(self.dot(Vector)/(self.magnitude*Vector.magnitude))
AttributeError: Vector instance has no __call__ method
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I create a `call` method for this class?

Comment: Your traceback doesn't match the code you posted. The code posted does exhibit the error though.

Comment: To create indentation I copied the code somewhere else and than copied it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your method signature:

```
def cross(self,Vector):  # and also the other methods
```

`Vector` argument is shading `Vector` class name. You should name your arguments differently, like `vector` in lower case.

Comment: or use `type(Vector)`, but renaming the local is the better option.

Comment: Yes but now after seeing your comment I am wondering the traceback relationship to the code

Comment: I suspect the code on disk doesn't reflect the code loaded in the interactive interpreter anymore. Bytecode contains the originating filename and line numbers and offsets, so a traceback re-reads the source to show matching source lines. But if you changed the file on disk in the meantime...

Comment: @zamk: It's a fairly common practice to call the argument `other` when defining such methods. This makes it clear the the argument can be another `Vector` or something derived from (or at least similar enough to) one to be provided.

Comment: @martineau: Thank you for the tip, i will consider using `other`.